# How to ignore the next same word as the first in a text using python?

Tags: python, string

I was wondering how to ignore or avoid the next same word as the first in some text using document?

I was searching for it but did not find any that close enough to what I'm imagining.

Let say I have these line in a text file

```
Group: 12 Cat: 100 Hen: 12 Cat: 200 Time: 328392 Cat: 123
```

I want the value for the first `Cat` only that is 100.
I know I can use `split` and `if-else` statement to find what I want like

```
if "Cat: 100" in line:
    value = line.split("Cat: ")[1].split("Hen: ")[0]
```

which will give me the result `100`

But what if I do not know the condition for it? For example I do not know the value of the first `Cat` whether it is 100 or 1242 or else?

Does anyone have any suggestion or solution for it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is very easy with a regex. In your case, `re.search('Cat: (\d+)', line).group(1)` (first, check if there is a match, then access `group(1)`).

Comment: what is the purpose of `group(1)` ? Is it for the first word of `Cat` ?

Comment: It is the value that is captured with the first set of unescaped parentheses in the pattern, i.e. `(\d+)` here.

Comment: When you search something with regex, and you enclose a pattern in parenthesis (like `(\d+)` in the example above), you can access different portions of the match object using `group(n)`. `group(0)` is always equal to the entire substring found (`Cat: 100`), `group(1)` is the first "grouped" pattern found (`100`). If you have multiple groups, then they follow the number given. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#match-objects for reference.